# enhancing a django model to incorporate external data in a query response

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to create a custom manager for my model class that still returns a lazy queryset, but incorporates some data in each object that is not stored in the database.  For simplicity, let's say I have something like:

```
class ProxyNodeManager(models.Manager):

    def _get_extra_data(self):
        # this would be something like a 3rd party API call
        return "abcdef"


class Node(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
     desc = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class ProxyNode(Node):
     objects = ProxyNodeManager()

     class Meta:
         proxy = True
```

A call to Node.objects.all() would return a QuerySet with name and desc fields, but a call to ProxyNode.all() would return a QuerySet that populates an 'extra' field that has the result of ProxyNodeManager._get_extra_data() as a value when the nodes are evaluated.

Any pointers?

Comment: For simple cases, have a look at annotate - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/ - also have a look at extra() to insert custom SQL. For API calls, you will have to go through the records via Python I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is not stored in SQL.  Still looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `iterator` method in `ProxyNodeManager`.

You can base on how [django does it](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.5/django/db/models/query.py#L1066).